# AdMob & Unity for iOS with custom AdUnit not showing Ads

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I'm having trouble with adMob (like I specified in the title) on my iOS game made with Unity.

I'm using Unity 5.5.5p1 with the adMob plugin.

Everything was fine when I use the testing adUnits, testing ads are showing perfectly, until I use the custom ones pasted from my adMob profile.
I'm building in release mode and my game isn't on the AppStore yet.

Thanks for the attention payed, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check if there's any **whitespaces** at the end of your copied ad unit id. It's the most common cause of not showing ads.
If that's fine, then most probably, you are getting **no fill** matching your custom AdUnit request, which is quite common in admob. If it doesn't get the matching size, it fails to show the ad.
You can see the debug log in the console for your connected device with actual ad id. If it shows, *No Fill*, then you may get sure that there's no ad currently available in the admob network, matching your given **size**.
I always prefer using the default sizes of admob, as they are more popular, there's always available ads in the network.

Comment: Thanks a lot! (: This helped me!